# Trying to download Google Trends data with multiple locations

Tags: r, csv, scrape, geography, google-trends

I'm trying to automate the download of Google Trends csv files from searches like the following: http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=%22volunteer%22%20%2B%22volunteer%201%22&geo=US-MO-604%2C%20US-MO-619&cmpt=geo

That is, I want to search for a term within multiple subnational locations, and pull down a csv that has one column of monthly search values for each of those places.

I've been using the code from [here](http://christophriedl.net/2013/08/22/google-trends-with-r/), and now have been trying to figure out how to add additional parameters.

Following the discussion on [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332243/trying-to-download-google-trends-data-but-date-parameter-is-ignored), I noticed that I could restrict the search by year if I include date="2011" in my call to getForm.  Similarly, I can restrict the search to the US by including geo="US".  But when I try to use the finer-grained geographic data that's in the URL above, such as geo="US-MO-604%2C%20US-MO-619" or even just "US-MO-604", it reverts back to just downloading the results of a worldwide search.  Is there a way to include this in my query?

Answer (score 1):

To get data from these geo locations in, for example, the year 2012, I used this URL:
http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=%22volunteer%22%20%2B%22volunteer%201%22&geo=US-MO-604%2C%20US-MO-619&date=1%2F2012%2012m&cmpt=geo&export=1&content=1.

This provided a .csv file that had only monthly data (I think that's all the more fine-grained you can get on the time dimension) for both of two geo locations you specified (Columbia-Jefferson City MO and Springfield MO).

This query seems to provide exactly what you're looking for: it did not revert to back to a worldwide search, and the CSV file only contained information about these two locations in the 12 months in 2012.